# How can I use Mac OS X (and UNIX) command line tools like grep with UTF-16 files?

Tags: macos, unix, unicode, grep, utf-16

I have a bunch of text files I want to use with grep. They are all from an external source and are UTF-16 encoded and begin with a byte order mark.

Unix tools like grep don't work on them for me. What work-around is there for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: does it work if you set the `LANG` environmental variable to something like `en_GB.UTF-16` (or whatever your locale is)?

Comment: @Bavarious, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work

Answer (score 8):

Just use iconv(1) to change them to utf-8.